# Write a formula which calculates the number of elements in B tree root after every i-th insertion

Tags: b-tree

Insert 1,2,..,20 numbers to the empty B tree sequentially. Write a formula which calculates the number of elements in B tree root after every i-th insertion. The first part I did, but I'm having trouble in the second part.

Here's what I did.

Let N be the maximum number of elements in the root of the B-tree.
If i ≤ N, the formula is: `R(i) = i`.
If N < i ≤ 2N, the formula is: `R(i) = N`.
If 2N < i ≤ 3N, the formula is: `R(i) = N + 1` and so on.
But by checking against the answer key, it seems I've done something wrong. Can you revise my solution and correct if it's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different insertion algorithms for B-trees, and the results you are looking for depend on them. I will here assume there is no pre-emptive splitting, and when a node is full there is no attempt to delay splitting by moving keys to sibling nodes.

Let's look at your statements:

> If i ≤ N, the formula is: `R(i) = i`.

Correct.

> If N < i ≤ 2N, the formula is: R(i) = N.

Not correct. When +1 is inserted, the root node splits into two nodes with each /2 keys, and one value is pushed up to become the only key in a new root node. So at that time `R(+1) = 1`. For example, if =4, then before inserting 5 we have:

```
root:
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Then after adding 5, we get:

```
             root:
            ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
            │ 3 │ - │ - │ - │
            ├───┼───┴───┴───┘
      ┌─────┘   └─────────┐
┌───┬─┴─┬───┬───┐   ┌───┬─┴─┬───┬───┐
│ 1 │ 2 │ - │ - │   │ 4 │ 5 │ - │ - │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘   └───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

> If 2N < i ≤ 3N, the formula is: `R(i) = N + 1`

That should have raised an alarm: a node could never have more than  elements, so obviously +1 is wrong.

After the tree has received its second level (so when +1 has been inserted), there is a sequence where the left side leaf node is filled, splits into two, adding one key in the root, and again the left side leaf node is filled, ...etc. At a certain moment the root gets full and splits into two, to get a tree with 3 levels and only one key in the root.

You may want to draw this on paper and see the logic.